# Update CRM 2011 using OrganizationServiceContext

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

How do you update records in CRM 2011 using OrganizationServiceContext? Can anyone provide a simple example? Thanks!

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services;
using System.Data.Services;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System;
using System.Web.Profile;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Caching;
using Telerik.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Discovery;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity;

public partial class LeadShareEditPanel : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}
protected void imgBtnSaveNote_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Uri organizationUri = new Uri("http://server/CRMT/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");
    Uri homeRealmUri = null;
    ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
    credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
    OrganizationServiceProxy orgProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(organizationUri, homeRealmUri, credentials, null);
    // Get the IOrganizationService

    //Get OrganizationServiceContext -the organization service context class implements the IQueryable interface and
    //a .NET Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) query provider so we can write LINQ queries against Microsoft Dynamics CRM data.

    using (var service = new OrganizationService(orgProxy))
    using (var context = new CrmOrganizationServiceContext(service))
    {
        var contact = context.CreateQuery<Contact>().First(c => c.FirstName == "Bob");
        contact.JobTitle = "Developer";
        context.UpdateObject(contact);
        context.SaveChanges();
        contact.EMailAddress1 = "bob@contoso.com";
        context.UpdateObject(contact);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: What issues do your have with your code? You will find examples in the [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24004)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example from the 5.05 SDK help file

```
using (var service = new OrganizationService(connection))
using (var context = new CrmOrganizationServiceContext(service))
{
var contact = context.CreateQuery<Contact>().First(c => c.FirstName == "Bob");
contact.JobTitle = "Developer";
context.UpdateObject(contact);
context.SaveChanges();
contact.EMailAddress1 = "bob@contoso.com";
context.UpdateObject(contact);
context.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you haven't already you can download the SDK from here [crm 2011 sdk](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24004) . I would highly reccomend it as it has lots of great samples. The current version is 5.06.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sounds like you missing some dll references or using statements. Check out this page from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695790.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I am still getting "CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Contact' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
" on this line of code var contact = context.CreateQuery<Contact>().First(c => c.FirstName == "Bob");
I posted my entire code above, I don't think I am missing any namespaces, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using early bound entities? Did you run the CRMSvcUtil.exe to generate OData objects? I've only ever used the early bound method so I'm not sure what you're missing. I found this [example](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/linq-query-crm-2011late-bound/) using late bound. You can see from that page that the guy uses a cast of (EntityReference) which is what you might have to do as well.